# How to scrollLeft onclick on a div within a div

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I have a container div with a set width and height and overflow set to scroll. Within that div is another content div which I can scroll. I want to add navigation elements that will automatically scroll to sepcified points (in pixels). I'm using Jquery currently and not getting anywhere. Any help would be awesome!

This is my HTML

```
<button class="scrollto"  style="position:fixed; top:100px;left:200px; width:150px;   height:50px; z-index:3;">purple_lamp</button>

<div id="container" >
  <div id="main_content">
    <img id="urban_chic" src="images/bg.jpg" />
    <img id="purple_lamp" src="images/purple_lamp.png" data-stellar-ratio="1.5"/>
    <img id="sofa" src="images/sofa.png" data-stellar-ratio="1.5"/>
    <img id="wall_clock" src="images/jacobs_wall_clock.png" data-stellar-ratio="1.5"/>
    <img id="yellow_shoe" src="images/yellow_shoe.png"  data-stellar-ratio="1.5" />
    <img id="intro" src="images/intro.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is my CSS

```
#container{
  height:768px;
  width:1024px;
  position:absolute;
  overflow:scroll;
}

#main_content{
  height:768px;
  width: 5454px;
  position:absolute;
}
```

And my JS

```
$('.scrollto').click(function() {
    $('#container').animate( { scrollRight: '+=500' }, 1000, 'easeOutQuad' );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `scrollRight` method, you'll still need to use `scrollLeft` and just invert the values:

```
$('.scrollto').click(function() {
    $('#container').animate( { scrollLeft: '-=500' }, 1000, 'easeOutQuad' );
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/TtXRZ/3/)

Comment: That didn't seem to work- is there something more I need to do to target that specific container?

Comment: Did you add jQuery UI or an easing plugin to use that easing, and are you sure you are targeting the scrollbars for the right element. Here's a working [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/TtXRZ/1/)